# I have two vectors u and v that both lie on z = 0. Can I find a quaternion axis to for these vectors if the axis must also lie on z?

Tags: vectors, rotations, quaternions

Vectors *u* and *v* both lie on the x-y plane or have a z value of zero. I understand that there is an infinite amount of quaternions that will rotate *u* to *v*. Is there a way to find an axis for a quaternion between these two points that also lies on the x-y plane or has a z value of zero? I've tried multiple ways to do this, however I am fairly new to the concept of quaternions and every axis I have found always deviates from the x-y plane. Is this quaternion even possible?

Comment: Question is very vague. You should be much more precise about how you are embedding $\mathbb R$or $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R^3$ or $\mathbb C^3$ into the ral quaternions or the complex quaternions.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I'm pretty new, I basically want to rotate point *u* to point *v* using a quaternion, but only if the axis of rotation can also be at z=0 just like the points. If that isn't enough how can I make this less vague?

Comment: Take as rotation axis a vector in the $x$-$y$ plane that halfs the angle between $u$ and $v$ and rotate by $180$ degrees. The translation of this to quaternion formalism can be done once you know what that rotation axis exactly is.

Comment: That's the issue of trying to find the rotation axis, is there a way to find its location if you know what the angle between vectors *u* and *v* is?

Comment: This is very simple if you visualise it. Bring $u,v$ to the same length by dividing each with their norm. So we assume from now on they have length one. Hint : what is the angle of $u+v$ with each of the other two vectors ?